# Android: Thumbnail stored in DB is returned null

Tags: android, sqlite, null

I have a Db where I have stored the path of a video and its thumbnail in ByteArray form. But when I try to retrieve the thumbnail from the DB I always get null value. Here is the code I am using to retrieve both the thumb and the path:

```
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("VideoPaths", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS paths(path VARCHAR,thumbnail BLOB);");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT path,thumbnail FROM paths",null);
        int index = c.getColumnIndex("path");
        int index2 = c.getColumnIndex("thumbnail");

        c.moveToFirst();

            if (c != null) {
                // Loop through all Results
                do {

                    String VideoPath = c.getString(index);
                    byte[] bytes = c.getBlob(index2);
                    Bitmap thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);


                    pathList.add(VideoPath);
                    listRow.add(new VideoRow(VideoPath,thumb, "User", "Testing"));

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
```

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue ?

P.S The video path retrieval is working fine.

EDIT: Here is the code that populates the table

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] thumbnailBitmapBytes = stream.toByteArray();

                    db=openOrCreateDatabase("VideoPaths", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO paths (path,thumbnail) values('" + serverPath + "','"+thumbnailBitmapBytes+"')");
```

Comment: Can you share your code which is used to populate the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would not construct your `INSERT` query by concatenating strings.  Take a look at `database.compileStatement(...)` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement(java.lang.String)).  Try doing this:

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO paths (path, thumbnail) values (?, ?)");
stmt.bindString(1, serverPath);
stmt.bindBlob(2, thumbnailBitmapBytes);
long newRowId = stmt.executeInsert();
```

Then, when it's time to fetch your data, you can use the code you've already shared.

Comment: Also whats the use of long newRowId ? Can't I just put stmt.executeInsert(); ?

Comment: Nevermind everything works fine ! Thanks a lot for your time! :D

Comment: the `long newRowId` value is there to allow you to do something with the SQLite `rowid` value for the new row.. you can ignore it if you don't need it :)